# Splitting field of a $q$, which divides $p$, is a subset of the splitting field of $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $p,q\in \mathbb{K}[X]$ be two polynomials and $\exists s\in \mathbb{K}[X]$ such that $q\cdot s=p$. Let $\mathbb{K}_p$ be the splitting field of $p$ and $\mathbb{K}_q$ be the splitting field of $q$. Is it always true that $\mathbb{K}_q\subseteq \mathbb{K}_p$?

Intuitively I would say it is true but unfortunately my algebra knowledge is very limited. I can't think of a counter-example.

Comment: The problem here is that splitting fields are not uniquely determined as sets. But they are, if you fix some algebraic closure of $\mathbb{K}$. In such a case, your statement is true.

Comment: @Crostul Do you mean by 'uniquely determined as sets' that there are multiple splitting fields that are subsets of each other? Then I want to know about the smallest splitting field. (Unfortunately it was years ago the last time I had to deal with abstract algebra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "a" splitting field, not "the" splitting field. Such fields are unique only up to isomorphism. But it *is* true that any splitting field of $p$ contains a splitting field of $q$.

Comment: Thank you. That was all I need.